# gcc expected identifier or '(

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a .c file, but the gcc throws this two errors:

```
Polarkor.c:15:11: error: expected identifier or '('
pol2cart(double r, double phi, double *x, double *y){
```

and

```
Polarkor.c:15:11: error: expected ')'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 

struct cor { int *x; int *y; };

struct pol2cart(double r, double phi, double *x, double *y)
{
    *(cor.x) = r * cos(phi);
    *(cor.y) = r * sin(phi);
    return cor;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double vecx, vecy = 4;
    pol2cart(1.0, M_PI / 4, &vecx, &vecy);
    printf("vec: x = %g, y = %g\n", vecx, vecy);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do not name an instance of a struct the same as the definition/tag name of the struct.

Comment: when compiling, enable all warnings. then you would see. 1) undefined variable name 'cor', 2) unused parameter argc, 3) unused parameter argv[], 4) unused parameter x 5) unused parameter y. 6) missing return statement in main, 7) variable vecx used without initialization,

Comment: I'll use -Wall next time for sure!

Comment: You just miss the `struct` tag for the return type of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 

struct cor {int x; int y;};

struct cor 
pol2cart(double r, double phi){  
  struct cor cor; /* legal, but generally a bad idea to use the same name */
  cor.x = r * cos(phi);    
  cor.y = r * sin(phi);     
  return cor;
}
```

In this, `struct cor` is an object type, and `cor` is the name of a local variable in the function `pol2cart`.  It is generally considered bad practice (indeed, terrible) to use the same name for the variable as the object type, but it is legal since the two are in different namespaces.  (Who says C doesn't have namespaces?!)  It looks like you were trying to create a global variable in your original code which could be done with:

```
struct cor { int x; int y;} cor;
```

but is probably a bad idea since it is unlikely that your program will use only one coordinate. It seems like `struct point` might be a better name.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct pol2cart(double r, double phi, double *x, double *y) { /* ... */ }
```

This looks like an incomplete definition of a function.
Its return type is `struct pol2cart` (which isn't defined) and it has no name.

Also

```
struct cor {int *x; int *y;};
```

defines a type named `struct cor` but no variables.
Later in your program you reference a variable named `cor` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The function does not have return type

```
struct  
pol2cart(double r, double phi, double *x, double *y){   
//...
```

And there is no object with name cor. So these statements

```
*(cor.x) = r * cos(phi);    
*(cor.y)= r * sin(phi);
```

are invalid. You may not use a structure name in these constructions. You have to create an object of the structure type that to access its data members.

Also parameters `double *x` and `double *y` are not used in the function.

The program does not make any sense.:)

Answer (score 0):

in the posted code:

```
**struct**  
pol2cart(double r, double phi, double *x, double *y){   
*(cor.x) = r * cos(phi);    
*(cor.y)= r * sin(phi);     
return cor;

}
```

that lone 'struct' is the problem.
Perhaps you meant 'void' or 'struct cor'

main ignores the returned value from a call to pol2cart()

I would suggest using 'void' and removing the return statement